# How to transfer sessionStorage to next tab

Tags: javascript, session, sessionstorage

I am using sessionStorage to store a value and when I open link in next tab sessionStorage automatically deleted. So can anyone tell me how to transfer sessionStorage to next tab. And I don't want  use localStorage.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)` is easy, but you'll need to loop to set the values... then again, to get the values from a new window based on a link, you'll have to use a shared worked or localStorage (temporarily) to send the json... with a tiny bit of js, you could replace the link with a button and pass the json along as window.name.

Comment: It's not deleted, the session is _bound to_ one tab.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `localStorage`? It seems to do just about exactly what you want.

Comment: @Siguza Is there a procedure to clear localStorage after close browser ??

Comment: @Siguza thankx bro its working